# How can I add a picture to my activity and how can I move it horizontally?

Tags: java, android, image, animation, audio

I've made an Android app that counts when two cars meet at a user defined speed from a user defined distance and I want to make an animation for the activity that show the results.

I have made the pictures and the audio, but I have problems inserting them and working with them. I have no idea how to move the pictures. I would like them to meet in the middle of the screen.

How can I the pictures and move them and how can I play an audio clip when they start moving and when they meet?